# how do i create a shortcode for a plugin page for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I have been having problems with including another plugin's function (namely WP Job Manager Resume) on my `WooCommerce` check out page.

I believe creating a shortcode would solve this immensely - would really appreciate if anyone would advise how I can create a shortcode for a plugin function, or any other alternative methods I can go about integrating these 2 plugins.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 add_shortcode( 'shortcode', 'your-function-name' );
```

Hope this helps.Cheers! ;)